# #define a unicode character

Tags: objective-c, unicode, c-preprocessor

I need to define the following 2 unicode constants

/*

Flat Symbol
 ♭
 MUSIC FLAT SIGN
 Unicode: U+266D, UTF-8: E2 99 AD

Sharp Symbol
 ♯
 MUSIC SHARP SIGN
 Unicode: U+266F, UTF-8: E2 99 AF

*/

```
#define kSongsSharpSymbol [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u0266F"]
#define kSongsFlatSymbol [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u0266D"]
```

When I look at the output in console, the value is not the correct symbol:

```
  NSLog(@"Sharp Constant %@",kSongsSharpSymbol);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Removing the leading zero fixed this:

```
#define kSongsSharpSymbol [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u266F"]
#define kSongsFlatSymbol [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u266D"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `stringWithFormat:` (as suggested by @Slinky) is unnecessary. Decoding the `\u` is done by the compiler, not the runtime. You can just use the string literal:

```
#define kSongsSharpSymbol @"\u266F"
#define kSongsFlatSymbol @"\u266D"
```